# Is it possible to create one-off (run to completion) jobs in Azure Container Apps?

Tags: azure, azure-container-apps

We have a job for running our DB migrations, that I would like to run on Azure Container Apps (it runs on Azure Container Instances now). The idea is that whenever we create a new migration, this job gets built and deployed, and then it triggers the migrations to run. Once the migrations have run, the job should just exit, and not get restarted. I haven't been able to find any information on how to create such a job in Azure Container Apps, except maybe it can be done in some clever way using the KEDA Cron scaler: https://keda.sh/docs/2.7/scalers/cron/

I am looking for any advice on how this can be achieved, or if this is just a bad idea for Azure Container Apps?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Keda would be a good option if you use something like a queue trigger: put a message in a queue to start the migration.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion @Thomas - however, I was hoping for an easier approach, as using a queue trigger would mean my build job would have to enqueue an item at the end, and it just does not seem like a good approach to me. Maybe I should just stick to Azure Container Instances, then :)

Comment: ACA is designed for reactive apps, not "jobs". I would suggest to stick with ACI for fire & forget jobs.

Comment: @devlearn ok, that was also my assumption after having struggled to find any documentation on running such jobs on ACA. Thanks for confirming!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Container apps now supports Jobs:

- [Jobs in Azure Container Apps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/container-apps/jobs?tabs=azure-cli#compare-container-apps-and-jobs)

In you case, you could use a manual job:

> Manual jobs are triggered on-demand using the Azure CLI or a request to the Azure Resource Manager API.

Manual jobs can be invoked using Az CLI, ARM/Bicep or from the portal.

Example using Az CLI:

```
az containerapp job create `
  --trigger-type "Manual" `
  ...
```